# How to pass Multiple parameters like env, credentials, cucumber tags from jenkinsFile

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to@ Jenkins and the first time and creating Jenkins's file.
I am using a maven project and in pom.xml I have added maven-surefire-plugin. inside the maven-surefire-plugin, I have passed the test runner file path.

How to pass multiple parameters from Jenkins file that would dynamically update properties file and test runner class. As per client requirement, I have to pass the environment name, credentials that are hardcoded in the properties file, and a cucumber tag, which is in test runner class. it should execute parallelly as well.
 Kindly share me code or suggest me a better way to implement.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass parameters like this as part of Jenkins pipeline.

```
parameters {
    string(name: 'value1', defaultValue: 'defaultValue', description: 'some description')
}
```

It also provides the UI where you can configure the parameters, see below the image.
[image]

You can refer the below link for more details.

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Define+Parameters

https://developers.perfectomobile.com/display/TT/Using+Jenkins+Build+Parameters

Comment: Thanks Sambit but how it will dynamically update it my properties file and test runner file.